# IIS Reverse Proxy Not Working With Response.Redirect() in ASP.NET

Tags: iis, rewrite, iis-7.5, asp.net, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up a reverse proxy, using the tutorials [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing), [here](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx) and [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/modifying-http-response-headers).

The site is set up on `localhost:8080`, with the reverse proxy using `localhost:8080/myProxy`.

When dealing with standard links, all is fine. I can view the proxy url and see everything as expected. A link from `localhost:8080/myProxy/default.aspx` goes to `localhost:8080/myProxy/about.aspx` as expected.

The problem I have is that where .NET `Response.Redirect()` is used, the url changes to the websites actual location instead of the proxy.

i.e. the link goes from `localhost:8080/myproxy/default.aspx` -> `localhost:8080/about.aspx`.

How can i resolve this please?

Here is my config:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" 
                    dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Reverse Proxy to my site" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^myProxy/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>

        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script"
                       pattern="^http(s)?://localhost:8080/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="/myProxy/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteRelativePaths" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" 
                       pattern="^/(.*)" negate="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="/myProxy/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>

    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I think this is worth putting out there for others info:

When using `Response.Redirect`, outbound rules come into play. Viewing the requests with Fiddler helped work out what was going on with the links.

`Response.Redirect()` was trying to send to `/About.aspx` (Transport in Response Headers).

This was not being picked up by the regex.

The only outbound rule I needed was [setting up `Response_location`](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/tips-tricks/handling-301-and-302-redirects-with-iis-7-url-rewrite/) as follows:

```xml
<rule name="Response Status Update" preCondition="ResponseStatus" stopProcessing="true">
  <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="^/(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" value="http://myServer:8080/myProxy/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The inbound rule remained unchanged.

Comment: Can you please share the precondtion ResponseStatus mentioned by you in the answer ? Thank you